# Javascript object array sort returns apparantly random results

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to get a simple sort working on an object array but it seems to be returning completely random results. Please have a look at this plunk: (in FF or Chrome)

http://plnkr.co/edit/TqoyUJV4nzvC4hAkVRkz?p=preview

```
    var data;
    var asc;

    function init(){
        data = [{username:"leonhaas"},{username:"0johnson"},{username:"leonlang"},{username:"0lechner"},{username:"0koller"},{username:"leonwinkler"},{username:"0schmidt"},{username:"0mueller"},{username:"0schmid"},{username:"lillyfuchs"},{username:"alexandragruber"},{username:"alexanderlechner"},{username:"alexanderpichler"},{username:"alexandraeder"},{username:"lillyreiter"},{username:"alibauer"},{username:"alexandrahall"},{username:"alexandrajohnson"},{username:"alexandrataylor"},{username:"alexandrawilliams"},{username:"lilywinkler"},{username:"alinabauer"},{username:"aliceegger"},{username:"alicesteiner"},{username:"alicewallner"},{username:"aliegger"},{username:"alifuchs"},{username:"linajohnson"},{username:"amarwhite"},{username:"alinaleitner"},{username:"alinaschmidt"},{username:"alinawood"},{username:"alischneider"}];
        outputData(data);
        asc = true;
    }

    function sortIt()
    {
        a = data.username;
        b = data.username;
        if(asc){
            data.sort(function(a,b)
            {
                return 1;
            });
        } else {
            data.sort(function(a,b)
            {
                return -1;
            });
        }

        outputData(data);
    }

    function outputData(data){
        var output = "";
        data.forEach(function (item){
            output += item.username +"<br>";
        });

        var x=document.getElementById("demo");
        x.innerHTML=output;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sorting function you have to compare data objects' usernames:

```
function sortIt()
{
    if(asc){
        data.sort(function(a,b)
        {
            return a.username.localeCompare(b.username);
        });
    } else {
        data.sort(function(a,b)
        {
            return b.username.localeCompare(a.username);
        });
    }

    outputData(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I found another way as well in the meantime:             data.sort(function(a,b)
            {
                var x = a['username'], y = b['username'];
                return (x == y ? 0 : (x > y ? 1 : -1));
            });

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things, you're not sorting the array, you need to return `0` if the values are the same, and then -1 (or 1) depending onascending/descending sorting.
Apart from that, you're assigning `var a` and `var b` in your `sortIt` function, true enough, but those aren't the values you'll be using in the `sort` callback. Because the arguments of the callback are the same name, they mask the `a` and `b` variables of the higher scope.

All things considered, the sort callback should look like this:

```
data.sort(function(a,b)
{
    return a.username === b.username ? 0 : a.username >b.username ? 1 : -1;
});
```

All things considered, your code can do with a lot more work: you're using global variables all over the place, your `sortIt` function will redeclare the sorting callbacks on each call, you're binding event handlers in HTML (always best to manage JS listeners in JS, sort-of Single Responsability-Principle), calling functions that could benefit from an actual relevant call-context etc... [look into IIFE's to create closures](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iife/info) for a start, and bookmark MDN

Answer (score 0):

You should return the value from the sort function based on the condition and not just 1 or -1. Like this...

```
// Inside your script.js. Line #14
if(asc){
    data.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        return a>b ? 1 : -1;
    });
} else {
    data.sort(function(a,b)
    {
        return a>b ?-1 : 1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortIt()
    {
        a = data.username;
        b = data.username;
        if(asc){
            data.sort(function(a,b)
            {
                if(a.username.localeCompare(b.username) > 0)
                return 1;
                else
                return -1;
            });
        } else {
            data.sort(function(a,b)
            {
                if(b.username.localeCompare(a.username) > 0)
                return 1;
                else
                return -1;
            });
        }

        outputData(data);
    }
```

Comment: no need for if/else, simply `return a.username.localeCompare(b.username)`

Answer (score 0):

```
        data = [{username: "leonhaas"},...];

        var asc = true;

        data.sort(function(a, b) {
            if (asc)
                return a.username > b.username ? 1 : -1;
            else
                return a.username > b.username ? -1 : 1;
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i].username);
        }
```